# Special effect on parsley min check error message, Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parsley.js

I am creating simple app with registration, that consists of multiple field types - string, text, check-boxes etc.

I added [parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html)  to display errors if any.  That works great.
But now I want to change color for heading when error happens - specially when parsley-min-check triggers it.

My code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3"> 
    Services
    <hr>          
  <div class="services-heading">  (Minimum*3)  </div>

    <div class="services-reg">

     <% @services.each do |service| %>
       <li>

            <%= check_box_tag 'service_ids[]', service.id, false, :'data-parsley-mincheck'=>3,:required => true%>
         <%= h service.name%>                       
       </li>               


     <% end %>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Now I am trying to trigger script when  desired div (services-reg) consists of parsley error message.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $( ".services-reg  > li.parsley-error").length ) {

        $(".services-heading > p").css("color", "red");
    }   
 });
```

but something isn't working as expected.
Console don't show any error message.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `.services-reg` has an `li.parsley-error` on your document ready. At that moment, you haven't performed any validation.

You can probably take advantage of [Parsley's events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events), such as `parsley:form:error`. So you can listen to that event, that is triggered when there's a validation error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // when there's a validation error
    $.listen('parsley:form:error', function(ParsleyForm) {
        $(".services-heading > p").css("color", "red");
    });
});
```

Check this [**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ok9kgydy/), where I'm also using `parsley:form:success` to remove the red color, when the form is correctly validated.

---

UPDATE: **If you have groups of divs** that contain a few fields and you want to change the color of the correct div, you can use the events `parsley:field:error` and `parsley:field:success`.

Example:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(ParsleyField) {
    var pElement = ParsleyField.$element.parent('div').prev().find('p');
    pElement.css("color", "red");
});
```

Here I'm finding the correct div based on the jQuery element for the input that has an error. You'll probably need to tweak this, based on the DOM of your form.

Take a look at this [**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ok9kgydy/1/).

Comment: Thanks, but my idea was to change heading color if exact div contains any parlsey error. In this case  services-reg. Is there any way to point that Parsley event to specific div ? Thanks again

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds Take a look at the updated answer. You can use events specific to the fields and then you need to find the correct div. Since you haven't post the structure of your form, I've "guessed" a bit and your structure might be different. If you have any issues, please edit your question and add the form structure.

Comment: Thanks, something still don't wan't to work. Now I don't get any change when Parsley error happens.. Also added some structure of my form.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds It might be easier if you can add the parsed HTML to your question (that is, the DOM after being parsed by rails - what you see in the "view page source"). I'm only seeing the divs `services-reg` and `services-heading` and I believe you might have more divs. Also include the beginning and end tags of the form. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But character limit won't allow to add full form with all divs..Is there any other way to target specific div for Parsley event.?

Comment: The best way to achieve what you want is with `parsley:field:error`. Most likely you need to adjust the jQuery selector to find the correct `<p>` element. If all the other divs follow the same "structure" as the one you have in your question, this should work: `var pElement = ParsleyField.$element.parent('div').parent('div').find('p');`. Check the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ok9kgydy/3/)